# String replacement of column names in python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, apply

I have a data frame `df` that contains 15 columns (See below)

`A_phase_1`,`A_phase_2`,`A_phase_3`,`A_phase_4`,`A_phase_5`, `B_phase_1`,`B_phase_2`,`B_phase_3`,`B_phase_4`,`B_phase_5`, `C_phase_1`,`C_phase_2`,`C_phase_3`,`C_phase_4`,`C_phase_5`.

While retaining columns with `phase_1` for example=`A_phase_1, B_phase_1 and C_phase_1`,

I want to programmatically do the following:

1. delete the columns containing `phase_2` that is = `A_phase_2`,`B_phase_2`,`C_phase_2`
2. replace the remainder column names `phase_n` with `phase_n-1`. for example,

all `phase_3` become `phase_2`;

`phase_4` -->  `phase_3`;

`phase_5` --> `phase_4`

So desired output should look like this :

`A_phase_1`,`A_phase_2`,`A_phase_3`,`A_phase_4`,

`B_phase_1`,`B_phase_2`,`B_phase_3`,`B_phase_4`,

`C_phase_1`,`C_phase_2`,`C_phase_3`,`C_phase_4`.

Thanks in advance!

@seaBean
I got this error

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the columns to delete.  Then, use [`df.columns.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with lambda function to rename the columns, as follows:

```
df = df.drop(df.filter(like='phase_2').columns, axis=1)

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: (x[:-1] + str(int(x[-1]) -1)) if (x[-1].isdigit() and (int(x[-1]) > 1)) else x)
```

**Input:**

```
print(df)

  A_phase_1 A_phase_2 A_phase_3 A_phase_4 A_phase_5 B_phase_1 B_phase_2 B_phase_3 B_phase_4 B_phase_5 C_phase_1 C_phase_2 C_phase_3 C_phase_4 C_phase_5 X_phase_t
0        A1        A2        A3        A4        A5        B1        B2        B3        B4        B5        C1        C2        C3        C4        C5        Xt
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

  A_phase_1 A_phase_2 A_phase_3 A_phase_4 B_phase_1 B_phase_2 B_phase_3 B_phase_4 C_phase_1 C_phase_2 C_phase_3 C_phase_4 X_phase_t
0        A1        A3        A4        A5        B1        B3        B4        B5        C1        C3        C4        C5        Xt
```

Comment: I need to use .filter more, the .drop line on your solution is very concise and readable!

Comment: @ClayShwery  Yes, it is a very handy function to filter columns with various methods.  It supports regex filtering too!  Really powerful.

Comment: @seaBean, the second code (the one wit the lambda function returns the error- `valueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't' `

Comment: @SeaBean, I have added the screenshot of the error to the initial post. Thanks

Comment: @RickyTricky  Your actual column names have some column(s) ends with 't' rather than a number ?

Comment: @SeaBean., Thanks for the observation. Works like magic!

Comment: @RickyTricky  I have edited the solution to support non-numeric last character column name without error.  It will simply retain those column names.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# 1.) delete phase 2 cols 
#    more precisely, keep only the other columns
df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col[-1]!='2']]
# This next could be done inline but keeping it separate here
rename_dict = {col:col[:-1]+str(int(col[-1])-1) for col in df.columns if col[-1] in ['3','4','5']}
df.rename(columns=rename_dict,inplace=True)
```